# Not able to display data from the form in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd created a form and I want to display the data entered in the form to another page. After I entered the details and hit signup it threw an assertion error:-

**A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'**

Here's the model.dart which has all the variables declaration:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Model {
  String fullname;
  String code;
  String standard;
  String section;
  String username;
  String password;
Model({this.fullname, this.code, this.standard, this.section, this.username, this.password});
}
```

Here's the student_signup.dart which has the form:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart' as validator;
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_student.dart';

class TestForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestFormState createState() => _TestFormState();
}
class _TestFormState extends State<TestForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Model model = Model();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.0;
return Scaffold(


  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Form(

          key: _formKey,

          child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[

              Container(

                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 130),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,


    child:  MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'Full Name',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter your full name';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          model.fullname = value;

                        },

                      ),


              ),

               new Row(

                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                  children: <Widget>[

                    Container(

                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,

                      width: halfMediaWidth,

                      child: MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'Class',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter your standard';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          model.standard = value;

                        },

                      ),

                    ),

    Container(

                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,

                      width: halfMediaWidth,

                      child: MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'Section',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter your section';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          model.section = value;

                        },

                      ),

                    ),



                  ],

                ),

              MyTextFormField(

                hintText: 'School Code',

                isEmail: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.isEmpty) {

                    return 'Please enter your school code';

                  }

                  return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  model.code = value;

                },

              ),

              MyTextFormField(

                hintText: 'Username',

                isPassword: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.length < 5) {

                    return 'Username should be at least 5 characters long';

                  }

    _formKey.currentState.save();

    return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  model.username = value;

                },

              ),

              MyTextFormField(

                hintText: 'New Password',

                isPassword: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.length < 7) {

                    return 'Password should be at least 7 characters long';

                  } else if (model.password != null) {

                    print(value);

                    print(model.password);


                  }

    return null;

                },

              ),

              RaisedButton(

                color: Colors.blueAccent,

                onPressed: () {

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                    _formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.push(

                        context,

                        MaterialPageRoute(

                            builder: (context) => Result(model: this.model)));

                  }

                },

                child: Text(

                  'Sign Up',

                  style: TextStyle(

                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),

                ),

              )

            ],

          ),

        ),
  ),
);
  }
}
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;
MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the homescreen_student.dart which will display the details from the form:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
 Model model;
 Result({this.model});
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Successful')),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(model.fullname, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(model.standard, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(model.section, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(model.code, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(model.username, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(model.password, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The error is displayed in the homescreen_student.dart. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgot to add `onSaved` Methos in Password field so it's pass the null instead of string of password. So, add the below code in password field,

```
onSaved: (String value) {

                  model.password = value;

                },
```

And One more suggestions to you, always use variable value in all Text field like below,

```
Text("${model.fullname}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22))
```